# Do you feel like DBA/DBD Is a "secure Field" still?

Tags: database-design

I noticed recently alot of Database jobs/Development have kind been pushed onto general developers, not to mention with NoSQL Solutions (Which IMO are probably a little easier for Non-DBA's to throw together) coming down the line. Do you feel like DBA/DBD (database developer) is a secure field for a CS Graduate to go in. Also...do you feel that Databases in General are still as popular as they were say....5-10 years ago?

For reference I do have a job as a Developer right now, but Databases is something that's always interested me.

I know theirs a Career Overflow site, but I'd prefer to keep it here since it's Specifically about Database Development/Administration.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Whether you use NoSQL (which means "not only SQL" not "no SQL") or an enterprise RDBMS, there is still quite a large need for architecture, data modeling, design, tuning, data security, etc. If you think throwing your databases on SQL Azure means you no longer need a DBA and it just runs itself, you might be in for a shock. Every company uses data in one way or another, and the trend I see developing is that more and more companies are moving to taking their data to big solutions. I don't anticipate the need for the DBA/DBD folks around that to dwindle, though I do sense that the nitty-gritty specifics involved in any such role are constantly evolving.